# Will I get the cards for Steam Christmas sale ever?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I was level 3 on Christmas sale (Steam), and I voted each 8 hours.
A message popped out, telling me that I'll receive my cards when I reach level 10.

I just crafted another badge, and I'm now level 10, but I don't have any new Snow Globe trading cards.

Am I going to get those cards, or I must wait until next sale / vote?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Snow Globe Trading Cards* for the *Steam Holiday Sale 2013* were [explicitly only available](http://web.archive.org/web/20140101040148/http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/snowglobefaq) during the sale:

> Unlike previous badges, once the sale ends the cards will disappear. Make sure to trade and craft your badges before Jan 3rd 11am PST.

The cards have, as such, since been removed from the system and will not be handed out anymore.

Comment: Your source link doesn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I've got a question related to it, and I thought it'd be better to ask here instead of a new one: does Steam usually ask for high levels, so it gives cards? I'm level 11, and I'd like to know if next time I'll have the opportunity to craft that badge without leveling up more (or at least not brutal levels as people who are 50+)

Comment: @AcidShout, you should ask that as a new question.  (In addition to being more likely to get an answer, it would help other people who have the same question.)

Answer (score 0):

The trading cards from the Christmas sale are no longer available.